# Colored hatched bar plot on overlapping / hidden bars with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Currently, I create my bar plot like this to compare two results

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
result_df.sym.plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none')
result_df.non_sym.plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none',color='orange')
```

This results in this

[image]

I want to show that the blue results generally outperform the yellow ones. But for some categories they do not, so they aren't visible at all.
What I now want is something like this:[image]

I quickly added this with powerpoint but of course I want to generate it directly with matplotlib/seaborn/pandas. But I have no idea how. There is the `hatched` parameter in matplotlib but it does not give the effect I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With matplotlib you can get this effect by plotting a third bar with the first dataset using only the hatch:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [4, 3, 2, 1]
                  })

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 10
mpl.rcParams['hatch.color'] = '#1F77B4'
df['A'].plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none', color='#1F77B4')
df['B'].plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none',color='orange')
df['A'].plot(kind='barh', color='none', hatch='/')
```

output:

[image: hatched plot 1]

or

```
df['A'].plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none', color='#1F77B4')
df['B'].plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none',color='orange')
df['A'].mask(df['B'].lt(df['A'])).plot(kind='barh', color='none', hatch='/')
```

output:

[image: hatched plot 2]

For thinner hatches:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 3
mpl.rcParams['hatch.color'] = '#1F77B4'
df['A'].plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none', color='#1F77B4')
df['B'].plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none',color='orange')
df['A'].mask(df['B'].lt(df['A'])).plot(kind='barh', color='none', hatch='//')
```

output:

[image: thin hatches]

Comment: Looks good!! But weirdly I cannot reproduce your results.
```import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 5
mpl.rcParams['hatch.color'] = '#1F77B4'

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
result_df.sym.plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none',color='#1F77B4')
result_df.non_sym.plot(kind='barh', edgecolor='none',color='orange')
result_df.sym.mask(result_df.non_sym.lt(result_df.sym)).plot(kind='barh', color='none', hatch='/')``` produces this https://imgur.com/a/tjJACQU

Comment: @JohanC using 3.5.1

Comment: yeah I am using quite an old version (3.3.4) because I have to use python 3.6 in my env because I have a library that requires python 3.6. I will try it in a separate plotting env

Comment: @sebko_iic Can you post the direct link to the image? I can't see it

Comment: @sebko_iic In those old matplotlib versions you could try `df['A'].mask(df['B'].lt(df['A'])).plot(kind='barh', facecolor='none', edgecolor='blue', hatch='//')`

Comment: @JohanC yeah that works :) it generates an ugly border though. I will try with a clean plotting env with never matplotlib version

Comment: @JohanC hmm it is the same with matplotlib 3.5.1

Comment: I found the problem. I had ```seaborn.set_theme()``` activated. Without this it works

Comment: You can use `lw=0` to remove the border.

Comment: @JohanC I do this. This is really annoying the seaborn theme looks much better than the plain matplotlib

Comment: @sebko_iic have you tried `plt.style.use('seaborn')`?

Answer (score 0):

sebko_iic. How about just drawing blues right under the yellows, or the yellows under the blues?
Just set the right offset in this line:
Details:
https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_MultilinePlots.html

Comment: yes this is definitely possible and I already generated this plot. But I do not have much space available and I find my proposed solution quite elegant to use as little space as possible